# DT export without format R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am exporting data with the button extension of `DT`. When clicking on `copy` or `excel` or `pdf`, format is also exported.

`DT` version 0.14 include format contrary to the old version 0.5 that is the comportement needed.

Reproducible exemple, `Sepal.Width` column with unit in meters in table that I don't want to export :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("dt_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$dt_table <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(
            iris,
            options = list(dom = 'lBfrtip', buttons = c('copy','excel', 'pdf')),
            extensions = 'Buttons'
        ) %>% formatString(
            columns = 'Sepal.Width',
            suffix = " meters"
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you know any argument to export dataset without formating ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps with the option `appendTo = "rowCallback"` in the `formatString` function.

Comment: Works at export but I lose units in shiny. Close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dt_table")
)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    return data + ' meters';",
  "  }else{",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$dt_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        dom = 'lBfrtip', 
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "copy",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          ),
          list(
            extend = "excel",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          ),
          list(
            extend = "pdf",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          )
        ),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 2, render = JS(render))
        )
      ),
      extensions = 'Buttons'
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

## EDIT

Another way:

```
tplString2 <- function(prefix, suffix, ...) {
  sprintf(
    "type === 'display' ? DTWidget.formatString(data, %s, %s) : data;",
    DT:::jsValues(prefix), DT:::jsValues(suffix)
  )
}

formatString2 <- function(table, columns, prefix = '', suffix = '') {
  DT:::formatColumns(table, columns, tplString2, prefix, suffix)
}

tplDate2 <- function(method, params, ...) {
  params = if (length(params) > 0) paste(',', jsonlite::toJSON(params)) else ''
  sprintf(
    "type === 'display' ? DTWidget.formatDate(data, %s%s) : data;", 
    DT:::jsValues(method), params
  )
}

formatDate2 <- function(table, columns, method = 'toDateString', params = NULL) {
  if (!inherits(table, 'datatables'))
    stop("Invalid table argument; a table object created from datatable() was expected")
  x = table$x
  if (x$filter != 'none') {
    if (inherits(columns, 'formula')) columns = all.vars(columns)
    colnames = base::attr(x, 'colnames', exact = TRUE)
    rownames = base::attr(x, 'rownames', exact = TRUE)
    if (is.null(params)) params = list()
    cols = sprintf("%d", DT:::name2int(columns, colnames, rownames))
    x$filterDateFmt = as.list(x$filterDateFmt)
    for (col in cols) x$filterDateFmt[[col]] = list(
      method = method, params = jsonlite::toJSON(params)
    )
    table$x = x
  }
  DT:::formatColumns(table, columns, tplDate2, method, params)
}

library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$dt_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        dom = 'lBfrtip', 
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "copy",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          ),
          list(
            extend = "excel",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          ),
          list(
            extend = "pdf",
            exportOptions = list(orthogonal = "export")
          )
        )
      ),
      extensions = 'Buttons'
    ) %>% 
     formatString2(columns = 1, suffix = " meters")
  })
  
}
```

Comment: @Clemsang Sorry. I've just edited my answer. This should work now.

Comment: Working thanks. I have different units and `formatString` would have been easier if you know a way to keep using it (I have also formatDate in my code).

Comment: @Clemsang See my edit. Use `formatString2` and `formatDate2`. You also have to set the `buttons` option as I do (with `exportOptions`).

Comment: It would have been great to have it in pure R DT without js, not yet. Seems a bit overkill to overloading functions but it will work. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Clemsang I proposed to the `DT` authors to include these modifications in the next release of `DT`. If they accept, you won't need to use these custom functions. But it seems they are on holliday.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Issue found I will follow it.